# Extract recipient from last item in sent mail folder in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to retrieve the recipient's name from the last e-mail sent from Outlook.

Using the Items.GetLast method returns the subject line, but I need the recipient's name.

I have tried looping through each item in the sent folder and extracting the information to a spreadsheet in Excel like this:

```
    For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
    For Each olRecipient In olMail.Recipients
        Cells(lngRow, 1) = olRecipient.Name
        Cells(lngRow, 2) = olRecipient.Address
    Next
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Next
Else
```

The problem I run into is when there is a sent item that is not of an olMail type, such as a meeting request response.  I end up getting a run-time error 13 Type mismatch.

For my purposes, I know that the last e-mail sent will always be the one that I need to get the recipient's name from, so it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to go through each item in the sent folder and grab the last one.  Is there a way to return the last e-mail sent item and extract the recipient's name?

I will be executing this command from an Excel workbook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that Items.GetLast will return the last sent item. The Items collection is not sorted in any particular way unless you expliiclyt call Sort():

```
set oItems = olFolder.Items
oItems.Sort("[SentOn]")
```

Secondly, GetLast() does *not* returns a string, it returns an object, which can be MailItem, MeetingItem, etc. If you need to handle items of different kinds, declare the item to be a generic Object and then check the Class property. It will be 43 (olMail) for the regular messages:

```
dim oItem As Object
set oItem = oItems.GetLast
if oItem.Class = 43 Then 
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the item type to avoid the `run-time error 13 Type mismatch`:

```
If TypeOf olMail is MailItem Then
   ...
End If
```